# How do I get all files filtering by a modified date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I need to get all the files in a chosen directory that were last modified in a specific date. E.g., get all the files that were modified in 2022-01-01.

I already get the last modified file/s in a directory.

```
import glob
import os

files_path = os.path.join(folder, '*')
files = sorted(glob.iglob(files_path), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True) 
print(files[0])
```

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a for loop?

Comment: `allfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]`

Use that and then filter one by one